# Subtracting Numbers larger than 18 digits in length

Tags: c++, sql-server, numbers, hex

Ok this is a tough one or else a stupid one but it has me stumped. I am working with serial numbers in MSSQL and they are stored in the database as nvarchar(50) and to do subtracting calculations on them I use the following query to convert them to the data-type BIGINT and subtract as normal.

```
SELECT
SUM(
CAST(second_Serial_Nb AS BIGINT)-CAST(Serial_Nb AS BIGINT))
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Serial_Table]
WHERE ID = '3'
```

this query works fine for serial numbers up to 18 digits in length, but as soon as I increase there size of the serial numbers to 20 digits in length I get the error that the numbers can not be converted to data-type bigint

```
Msg 8815, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint
```

Is there a work around using a different number data type like hexi or something. I am also using C++ maybe I could create a function there instead of SQL?

Any comments or suggestions greatly appreciated, Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

`BIGINT` is just a normal, 64-bit integer. It is *not* an arbitrary-precision integer.

If you want to store more information, you can either keep it in string form, or use a `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` type; both solutions are of course much slower than a native, fixed-width integer.

Comment: Hi @Kerrek SB, it is stored in the DB as a string but I need to subtract each serial from one another to see what the range is. If I have a serial which is 20 digits in length like '12345678998745632145' and another like '12345632145236578941' I can not subtract them from one another as I can not convert them to a suitable data-type or number format

Comment: @OMUIRI: You can convert them both to `NUMERIC`.

Comment: @OMUIRI you can do the subtraction by putting the number in linked list and subtract both linked list and get the result back in form of linked list.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: What **NUMERIC** data-type in MSSQL will be able to represent a nvarchar(21) like "1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 2" as a **NUMERIC** data-type? As I suggested **BIGINT** but it is not sufficient.